# mongoengine push using $sort and $slice

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I would like to perform something similar to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#use-push-operator-with-multiple-modifiers) using MongoEngine, but without the $each:

```
db.students.update( { _id: 5 },
                    { $push: { quizzes: { { wk: 5, score: 8 },
                                          $sort: { score: -1 },
                                          $slice: 3
                                        }
                             }
                    }
                  )
```

I know that I can perform an `update/update_one(push__quizzes={wk: 5, score: 8})` and (maybe) a `update/update_one(push__quizzes={wk: 5, score: 8}, slice__quizzes=3)`. Would that be correct? Finally, and most importantly, how do I add the equivalent $sort?

Thanks!

**Would generate error**: `Unexpected token {`

Answer (score 1):

From a MongoDB perspective you cannot use $sort or $slice as part of a $push without $each, as noted in the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/).